# nodejs mysql query doesn

Tags: mysql, node.js

I want to check if some date exist in a table, if not I want to insert it. I have done this in other project and there it works but now i don't know why it doesn't work.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
   host     : '',
   user     : '',
   password : '',
   database : ''
});

[..]

connection.query('SELECT id FROM users [...]', function(err, results) {
    if (err) {
         throw err;
    } else if (results.length==1) {
         callback(null, results[0].id);
    } else {
         console.log('before insert');
         connection.query('INSERT INTO users SET ?', user, function(err, result) {
             console.log('insert');
             if (err) throw err;
         });
    }
});
```

The query with INSERT doesn't work, but if i get that query out of the SELECT query then it works. 
Doesn't matter if it is INSERT or other query.
In console I only see: 'before insert' and no error.
This query it's in a loop.

Comment: Insert syntax is : `insert into t (col1, col2) values (?, ?)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have syntax error in insert statement, it has to be:

```
 connection.query('INSERT INTO users (`id`) VALUES (?)', user, function(err, result) {
     console.log('insert');
     if (err) throw err;
 });
```

You could also optimise the code to run a single query only, using `INSERT IGNORE` syntax. If record already exists, MySQL will just ignore the insert, without giving any errors. But your field `id` has to be set as `primary key`.

Optimised, the code will look like:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
   host     : '',
   user     : '',
   password : '',
   database : ''
});

[..]
connection.query('INSERT IGNORE INTO users (`id`) VALUES (?)', user, function(err, results) {
    if (err) {
         throw err;
    } else {
         callback(null, user);
    }
});
```